# WordPress loop that lists titles and content separately

Tags: php, html, loops, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and would like to create a loop that would list post titles (only from one category) in the left div, and the content of the same posts in the right div. This is what i did and I am wondering if there is a better way to do it (well, there probably is)? Thanks!

```
<div class="container">
<div class="post_title">
    <?php query_posts('cat=6'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <?php rewind_posts(); ?> 
</div>          
<div class="post_content">
    <?php query_posts('cat=6'); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: **NEVER EVER** use `query_posts`. It is slow, breaks the main query, and breaks page functionality. You can do everything in **one** query. I have done something like this a couple of months ago, although I cannot remember where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use get_posts instead: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

```
$output1 = '';
$output2 = '';
$args = array('cat'=> 6);
$allposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $allposts as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post );
  // Store the titles in one variable
  $output1 .= '<h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3>';
  // And the content in another
  $output2 .= wpautop(get_the_content());
endforeach;
wp_reset_query();
```

Then echo out $output1 and $output2 where you need them - you could even store them as arrays if you want more control. You can add parameters to the $args array to change the order etc as you wish.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful!

Comment: Glad it helps - let me know if you need any further help. Learning the get_posts function will help you a lot with WordPress development. The WordPress codex is your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

It not good,same code run twice,you can use get_the_title(),get_post(),get_the_content() instead in one loop,they return string rather than output string immediately.

Comment: Thanks! Problem is that  in one loop I get a result in this order - title, content, title, content and I need title, title, content, content. I need to lists, one listing the titles and other listing the content